# convert JSON array of foreign keys to comma separated list of names (from other table's field) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine that I have the following tables in a SQL Server database.

```
table name: products

 id  product_name 
 1   "Apple"
 2   "Banana"
 3   "Pear"
 4   "Peach"


 table name: users 

 id  user_name     likedProductsIds (JSON array of row ids for product table)
 1   "Joe"         "[1,2,3,4]"
 2   "Jose"        "[3,4]"
 3   "Kim"          NULL
 4   "Kelly"       "[4]"
```

I am looking for a query I could save as a SQL "view" to convert the JSON array "likedProductsId" into a comma seperated list of names of products. Such that the result would be:

```
 view name: report
 id  name     likedProductNames
 1  "Joe"     "Apple, Banana, Pear, Peach"
 2  "Jose"    "Pear, Peach"
 3  "Kim"      NULL,
 4  "Kelly"   "Peach"
```

I am a SQL newbee so I am have been really struggling with this due to the complexity of deserializing the JSON field and aggregating the results into a single comma separated string. I know some ingredients I will need such as OPENJSON to deserialize the IDs array and STRING_AGG to combine the product names into a single string, but I am lacking the glue to get them togther

```
 SELECT id, name FROM users
 LEFT JOIN what....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option that uses `OPENJSON` in concert with an `CROSS APPLY`.

In order to maintain the sequence, we use  `... within group (order by [key])`

**Example**

```
Select U.id
      ,U.user_name
      ,P.likedProductNames
 From  users U
 Cross Apply (
                Select likedProductNames = string_agg([product_name],',') within group (order by [key])
                 from  OpenJSON([likedProductsIds]) A
                 Join  products B on A.value=B.id
             ) P
```

**Results**

```
id  user_name   likedProductNames
1   Joe         Apple,Banana,Pear,Peach
2   Jose        Pear,Peach
3   Kim         NULL
4   Kelly       Peach
```

**UPDATE**

Oddly enough, this may be a nudge more performant.  (relative to the batch) : 30% vs the Cross Apply 37%

```
Select U.id
      ,U.user_name
      ,likedProductNames = (
                            Select string_agg([product_name],',') within group (order by [key])
                             From  OpenJSON([likedProductsIds]) A
                             Join  products B on A.value=B.id
                           )
 From  users U
```